# Passing a Command to a Comm Port Using C#'s SerialPort Class

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, serial-port

I'm currently trying to pass a specific command from an example test application written in VB6. In VB6 the command looks like:

```
Comm1.Output = "UUT_SEND ""REMS\n"" " + Chr(10)
```

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to pass that same data via C#'s SerialPort class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sending stuff out the serialport is relatively straight forward....

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
serialPort.Write("UUT_SEND \"REMS\\n\" \n");
```

To get any responses you will have to hook the DataReceived event.

Comment: Quote from the manual: For example, “UUT_SEND ““REMS\n”” ”. Note the use of \n, which indicates a
Carriage Return (CR) as the end-of-line character. Other characters include \r (Line
Feed), \t (Tab), \b (Backspace) and \f (Form Feed). Also note the double quotes
around <uut command> to show embedded quotes.

Comment: Did you mean whether \n is literal or a carriage return?

Comment: I'm rather terribly confused. The manual refers to \n as Carriage Return and \r as Line Feed. Is this correct? I believe \r is Carriage Return and \n is New Line in C#.

Comment: And I need to know for a fact whether \n is literal or a (in the case of what the manual says) carriage return. I'm passing commands to a $25,000 piece of equipment. I can't afford mistakes.

Comment: just looked it up ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e.aspx   \n = NL = Ascii 10 decimal   \r =  CR = Ascii 13 decimal.   In this case the Chr(10) = \n

Comment: also looked up VB6,  apparently the \n in your string is literal

Comment: Submitted another question enquiring about further info as to SerialPort here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552268/c-sharp-serialport-class-usage